# Write a Java class "Sort" which implements the BubbleSort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

For a further education I had to do the following task:

> Implement the BubbleSort algorithm within the Java class
>   `algorithm.Sort`.
>
> Submit your solution to the `JUnit` system for automatic evaluation.

Here the source code of my `Sort` class. The requirements concerning the single methods I've added as comments.

```
package algorithm;

public class Sort
{
    /*
        Sort the complete field in ascending order.
    */   
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] list)
    {
        Sort.bubbleSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }

    /*
        Sort the field ascending from leftIndex to rightIndex.
        Implement the BubbleSort algorithm.
        One has to specify a lower and an upper index.
        These range of the array is then sorted by BubbleSort.
        The lower and the upper index have to be checked for validity.
    */
    public static void bubbleSort(int[] list, int leftIdx, int rightIdx)
            throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (leftIdx < 0 || leftIdx > list.length - 1 
                || rightIdx < 0 || rightIdx > list.length - 1) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Left or right index invalid.");
        }

        for (int i = list.length; i > 1; i--) 
        {                
            for (int j = leftIdx; j < rightIdx; j++) 
            {                   
                if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) 
                {
                    int tmp = list[j];

                    list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    list[j + 1] = tmp;
                }                    
            }
        }
    }

    // The largest element within the specified array-range
    // has to be moved to position i.
    // Basically just the inner loop of BubbleSort.
    // Parameter validity checks required.
    public static void bubbleUp(int[] list, int leftIdx, int i)
    {
        if (leftIdx < 0 || leftIdx > list.length - 1 
                || i < 0 || i > list.length - 1) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Left or right index invalid.");
        }

        while (leftIdx < i) 
        {                
            if (list[leftIdx] > list[leftIdx + 1]) 
            {
                int tmp = list[leftIdx];

                list[leftIdx] = list[leftIdx + 1];
                list[leftIdx + 1] = tmp;
            }

            leftIdx++;
        }
    }

    // Convert the array to a appropriate String representation!
    // Parameter validity checks required.
    public static String toString(int[] list, int start, int end)
    {
        if (start < 0 || start > list.length - 1 
                || end < 0 || end > list.length - 1
                || start > end) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Left or right index invalid.");
        }

        String ret = "";

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) 
        {
            ret += list[i] + ", ";
        }

        return "[ " + ret.substring(0, ret.length() - 2) + " ]";
    }

    // Return the complete array as an appropriate String representation.
    public static String toString(int[] list)
    {
        return Sort.toString(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Here's the Java class which I've made for myself, so I could test my code while developing:

```
package test;

import algorithm.Sort;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class SortTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] test = { 9, 16, 17, 5, 3, 18, 14, 4, 14, 17 };
        out.println("Before: " + Sort.toString(test) + "\n");

        Sort.bubbleSort(test);

        out.println("After: " + Sort.toString(test));

        /*  RESULT :
            Before: [ 9, 16, 17, 5, 3, 18, 14, 4, 14, 17 ]

            After: [ 5, 3, 4, 9, 14, 14, 16, 17, 17, 18 ]        
        */
    }    
}
```

My class passed the automated tests, so it might be correct formally. I would appreciate comments and critiques from other developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No unnecessary math

> ```
>         if (leftIdx < 0 || leftIdx > list.length - 1 
>                 || rightIdx < 0 || rightIdx > list.length - 1)
> ```

You could simplify this to

```
        if (leftIdx < 0 || leftIdx >= list.length 
                || rightIdx < 0 || rightIdx >= list.length)
```

Because if either `Idx` is equal to `list.length`, it is greater than `list.length - 1`.

#### Don't do extra work

> ```
>         for (int i = list.length; i > 1; i--) 
>         {                
>             for (int j = leftIdx; j < rightIdx; j++)
> ```

You're doing more passes than necessary.

```
        for (int i = rightIdx; i > leftIdx; i--) 
        {                
            for (int j = leftIdx; j < i; j++)
```

This works by bubbling the largest element to the end.  Once that's done, we don't have to review the end again.  So we can decrease `i`, which points to the end.

#### Bubble Sort best case

> ```
>         for (int i = list.length; i > 1; i--) 
>         {                
>             for (int j = leftIdx; j < rightIdx; j++) 
>             {                   
>                 if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) 
>                 {
>                     int tmp = list[j];
>
>                     list[j] = list[j + 1];
>                     list[j + 1] = tmp;
>                 }                    
>             }
>         }
> ```

One of the advantages of bubble sort is that it is possible to get a best case of linear time.  However, this code doesn't do that.  It's always quadratic, regardless of whether the data is already sorted.

Consider

```
        for (int i = rightIdx; i > leftIdx; i--) 
        {
            Integer tmp = null;

            for (int j = leftIdx; j < i; j++) 
            {                   
                if (list[j] > list[j + 1]) 
                {
                    tmp = list[j];

                    list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    list[j + 1] = tmp;
                }                    
            }

            if (tmp == null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Now if we never swap, then `tmp` is `null` and we stop processing.  If the `list` is sorted, that happens on the first outer iteration and we only go through the `list` once.  If the code is almost sorted but not quite, it could happen after just a few iterations.

If you add data at the end a lot, note that reversing the sort so that it bubbles the smallest forward rather than the largest back would help.

#### `StringBuilder`

> ```
>         String ret = "";
>
>         for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) 
>         {
>             ret += list[i] + ", ";
>         }
>
>         return "[ " + ret.substring(0, ret.length() - 2) + " ]";
> ```

This should use a `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation.

```
        String Builder ret = new StringBuilder("[ ");

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) 
        {
            ret.append(list[i]).append(", ");
        }
        ret.append(list[end]).append(" ]");

        return ret.toString();
```

Now rather than creating new strings each time, it just expands the `StringBuilder` as needed.

I also changed it so that the `substring` call is unnecessary.  Since we're manually iterating anyway, we can just not do the last element inside the loop.  That way we can handle it separately outside.

The `substring` trick makes more sense when we're automating the iteration such that we can't control the bounds.  But that's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other parts of mdfst13s answer, note that standard functions like converting things to strings hardly need to be implemented manually anymore. Instead of using a StringBuilder and manual looping, you can simply stream your ints into a joining collector:

```
retrun Arrays.stream(list, start, end  + 1)
             .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
             .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[ ", " ]"));
```